# Algorithm / API for converting HTML to email friendly HTML (for newsletters)

Tags: algorithm, email, language-agnostic, html-email, newsletter

I'm sure this is a very old question, but I could not find a straight answer

I'm looking for a works-mostly algorithm to take regular HTML content, and make it email client friendly.

I can rewrite any nice DIV layout to table layout, this is OK, but is there anything that will do it for me?

Here are my concerns

- Overflow content - gmail etc ignores any overflow:hidden, the algorithm should address it
- Clipped images - same as above, but here the solution will probably be server side clipping
- CSS / Script / non standard tags - the algorithm should remove but keep the general look and feel
- DIV layout to table layout, I heard it's a must, but I'm sure it's not an easy task to automate

There are many HTML to PDF converters, but I could not find a good HTML to "HTEMAIL" converter

Is there any standard or proposed standard for HTML for email clients? or is it an open jungle out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make a converter that will be cross email client compatible. The closest you can get is using templates and adding text in certain sections using php or .net

I've been creating emails for 6 months, and the amount of time you spend correcting email client differences is normally around 50% of the time you spend making the email.

Here is some reading that may help you:

http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

As you can see from that last link there is no way to create an algorithm that can sort out all these issues.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Another option that I've been using is to build the email in HTML or directly in Mailchimp. Once I'm happy with it, using Mailchimp, I click on preview and I get the email in a popup. The source code from the popup is email-client friendly (in tables). I then copy that code and use it for my emails.

Not ideal and a bit of trouble, but so far the best solution I can find.

And before people ask, I mostly us Mailchimp directly, but there is one situation that I have to kick it old school.